# What was the "cyclops' smoky band" to which Ewan MacColl's father belonged?

Tags: meaning, song-lyrics

Ewan MacColl's song "My Old Man" contains the lyrics:

> My old man was a good old man
>   Skilled in the moulding trade
>   In the stinking heat of the iron foundry
>   My old man was made
>   Down on his knees in the moulding sand
>   He wore his trade like a company brand
>   He was one of the **cyclops’ smoky band**
>   Yes, that was my old man

Who was this cyclops, and what was his smoky band?

Comment: There was a Cyclops Steel & Iron Works in Sheffield, but based on a quick skim of Wikipedia, Ewan MacColl's father can't have worked there.

Comment: @GarethRees It's not impossible, but it does seem very unlikely. Really surprising there's not more information on this.

Comment: Suspect this may be related: Cyclops works of Sheffield and Openshaw works of Manchester merged in 1928 to create the English Steel Corporation. They retained a site in Openshaw. Can't find anything to verify my supposition though https://www.gracesguide.co.uk/English_Steel_Corporation

Comment: Of course the song might be fictional and not autobiographical.

Comment: It could well be, but it seems dubious that he pulled *Cyclops' smoky band* out of the air simply because it rhymed with *a company brand*. He was obviously a pretty good writer :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the work of the Greek poet [Hesiod](https://www.britannica.com/topic/Cyclops-Greek-mythology), the three cyclops,

> Arges, Brontes, and Steropes (Bright, Thunderer, Lightener)—[...] forged
>   the thunderbolts of Zeus. Later authors made them the workmen of
>   Hephaestus and said that Apollo killed them for making the thunderbolt
>   that slew his son Asclepius.

This would be the connection which led to the naming of the Sheffield ‘Cyclops Works’, that @GarethRees cited in comments, but which equally applies to all foundry men.

Working molten metal is a dangerous trade, sparks fly and no doubt the classical link of one eyed creatures with foundry work reflects a tendency of those in that trade to lose eyes, particularly before glass eye protection became possible and common.

The song also contains the line

> They'll rob you blind if you don't fight

Which makes me wonder if his father had his eyesight damaged by the work. But even if not, cyclops were iron shapers to the Gods, Pa MacColl was one of their trade, and foundries are smokey places.

Comment: Sense this makes!